# could we use youtube video player in our website with our own video(video does not upload to youtube server)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video-streaming, html5-video, video-player

I am looking for the best video player to use on my offline website I tried with some video players but it does not work well. sometimes it is stuck when user try to stream it. If have some video players as youtube player and we can use it offline is the best practice for my requirement. if someone know this please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: thank lonut for your answer, but do you know other player that we can embedded in our website and its perform as youtube player or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Videos which are hosted by YouTube are only available to be on the YouTube player.

Like other users have said, you may be interested in HTML5 video. All major browsers will support it.

There are also 3rd party libraries which offer HTML5 video. http://videojs.com/ is a popular one.

Comment: ohhh yeah I see. KA-lite also use this one. thank Sam Bunting.

Answer (score 1):

you can use HTML5 video tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

e.g:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: thank bubjavier, I have already tried this one but the problem is I use my website in offline server to allow student in access and watch video when number of student increase to stream the video so video is stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe can use HTML5 to Solve that, i hope help with this Link on [HTML5 Video Player](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video), if not solve your problem or if you have some questions ask! :)

```
<video width="400" controls>
   <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: thank Pedro Monteiro Anrates, I have already tried this one but the problem is I use my website in offline server to allow student in access and watch video when number of student increase to stream the video so video is stuck.

Comment: @SimChomroeun, You want to allow students see the video at same time, right?

Comment: yeah I want to allow students see the video at same time.

Comment: So VideoJS is the best option for you! :)